# how to change directory permissions

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

i want every directory permission set to 755. So i want to change any directories having permission other 755 to 755. How can i change this without even touching the directories which is already set to 755 permission.
I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: What do you mean 755 to 755?

Answer (score 2):

Note that you probably don't want to do this (and you definitely don't want to do this on system directories) but if you're sure then

```
find /path -type d ! -perm 755
```

will find all of the directories in /path that don't have 755 as a perm

After reviewing the list then

```
find /path -type d ! -perm 755 -exec chmod 755 {} +
```

should do what you want.

Comment: I think that the syntax is not quite logical. E.g Directories having permissions 777 will also be getting perms 755.

Comment: i'm making the changes in my usb drive not in system files..thank you for the answer

Comment: do you have any other answer val0x00ff..

Comment: @val0x00ff: That's exactly what the OP appears to have asked for isn't it - all directories not currently 755 set to 755 ?

Comment: @lain I probably misread the question. But if all directories(regardless their current permission status) are to be 755 then the syntax is of course correct. The question still has to be re-articulated.

Answer (score 1):

You simplay can run `find` and change directories to 755. Example below

`find /path/to/dir -type d ! -perm 755 -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

`find . -type d -not -perm 0755 -exec chmod 0755 '{}' \;` should help you !